# How can I use the newly insert record's id in MySQL's PROCEDURE?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

For example, I have a `users` table, and `waitingUsers` table:
They work like this:

```
`Users`:
id
name
```

and

```
`WaitingUsers`:
id
user_id
```

Both `Users` and `WaitingUsers`'s id is auto increment. 
I would like to have one `PROCEDURE` to create the users, and the new `id` is generated after the users is created, and use it inserts into `waitingUsers`. How can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRecord(IN _name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users VALUES (_name);
    INSERT INTO WaitingUsers VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function%5Flast-insert-id)

or

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRecord(IN _name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users (id, Name) VALUES (NULL, _name);
    INSERT INTO WaitingUsers (id, user_id) VALUES (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID());
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What if concurrency is an issue?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the first value assigned by an auto-increment column during the most recent insert done by your session, regardless of what else might have been inserted into the table by other sessions subsequently, so concurrency is not an issue.  I say "first value assigned" because if you insert multiple rows in a single statement, the first value is the one you get back with this function.